# Display: inline-block doesn't work property on phone

Tags: html, css

I have problem with displaying the divs. On pc it works well but on phone last div is in new line and i dont know why. Anyone can help me? Here is part of code and screens. Thanks!

```
    <div class="Ctoplinks">
        <div style="margin-left:0px;">
            Link
        </div>
        <div>
            Link
        </div>
        <div>
            Link
        </div>
        <div>
            Link
        </div>
        <div>
            Link
        </div>
    </div>

.Ctoplinks{
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 720px;}

.Ctoplinks div{
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px #37475a;
    border: 2px solid #37475a;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;}
```

[Screen from PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ampUc.png)
[Screen from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7fX.png)

Comment: It goes to the next line because it doesn't fit on the current line, just like any other word. Try turning your phone to landscape and see that it stays on the same line as the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reduce the `margin-left` on the links, but if the sum of the widths of the inline-blocks plus the margins between them still exceeds the screen width, the only thing you can do is to reduce the font-size to make them smaller (or use a condensed-type font).

Comment: Ok, I reduced margin on smaller resolution and it works. Thanks.